# Can a secondary members of a replica set reside in a different specified zone for the primary member?

Tags: mongodb

If I replicate a collection 2 times, have a shard key on a country field, and specify 2 zones for North American countries and European countries, a document with country = America will be routed to the shards in the North American zone for the primary replica, but what about the secondary members of the document with America as its country?

Comment: You are confusing sharding and replication. Zones are attached to shards, not to replica set members.

Comment: Why shouldn't zones attach to replica set members of a shard? Can I configure it so that replicas do not cross zones?

Comment: A secondary member is always a full copy of the primary. There is nothing you could configure different.

Comment: zones are logical configuration set per shard  , but afcourse you can move replicaSet members from same shard in different geographical locations ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
shard1(zone1)-->    PRI(America)   SEC(Africa)   SEC(Europe)
shard2(zone2)-->    SEC(America)   PRI(Africa)   SEC(Europe)    
shard3(zone3)-->    SEC(America)   SEC(Africa)   PRI(Europe)
```

You set zone1=America , zone2=Africa , zone3=Europe and you locate the members as described above per continent ...
When you write from America you will write to zone1 where the PRIMARY(America) is located.
When you read from other continent american data it is best to send the reads with readPreference: "NEAREST" so the app to read from Europe or Africa whatever SECONDARY is closer to avoid the latency for already replicated data to the other locations ...

(This is with the idea to have inter continental  geo-distribution , high availability , redundancy and horizontal scalability  )

Let me know if this example clarified the zones abit? ;)